# C# EWS copy contacts to a mailbox

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to select the user "test" so I can create a contact into his mailbox.

My actual problem is that it will create Contacts into my user "c-sharp".

"c-sharp" has full access on "test" mailbox

I changed the IP and the contact infos users are also only for testing.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
service.EnableScpLookup = false;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("c-sharp", "c-sharp", "domain");
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
IgnoreBadCertificates();
service.Url = new Uri("https://192.000.000.000/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

Contact contact = new Contact(service);

// Specify the name and how the contact should be filed.
contact.GivenName = "n.a.";
contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameCommaGivenName;
contact.DisplayName = "bau gmbh";

// Specify the company name.
contact.CompanyName = "bau";

// Specify the business, home, and car phone numbers.
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = "00000 00000";
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone] = "n.a.";
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessFax] = "00000 00000";

// Specify two email addresses.
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress("e@mail.de");

//homepage
contact.BusinessHomePage = "n.a.";

// Specify the home address.
PhysicalAddressEntry paEntry1 = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
paEntry1.Street = "straße";
paEntry1.City = "stadt";
paEntry1.State = "D";
paEntry1.PostalCode = "88890";
paEntry1.CountryOrRegion = "Deutschland";
contact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = paEntry1;
contact.Save();
```

Already tried this:

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "test");
```

I tested it with "test" and "test@domain" and "test@domain.de"
And get back this error: 

"Der Name des Identitätsprinzipals ist ungültig."
Own translation: "The name of the identity principal is unvailed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Impersonation like this

```
ExchangeUserData exchangeUserData = new ExchangeUserData();
exchangeUserData.Username = "c-sharp";
exchangeUserData.Password = "c-sharp"; // c-sharp's Password

ExchangeService service = Service.ConnectToServiceWithImpersonation(exchangeUserData, impersonatedUserPrincipal);

Contact contact = new Contact(service);

// Specify the name and how the contact should be filed.
contact.GivenName = "n.a.";
contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameCommaGivenName;
contact.DisplayName = "bau gmbh";

// Specify the company name.
contact.CompanyName = "bau";

// Specify the business, home, and car phone numbers.
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = "00000 00000";
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone] = "n.a.";
contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessFax] = "00000 00000";

// Specify two email addresses.
contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress("e@mail.de");

//homepage
contact.BusinessHomePage = "n.a.";

// Specify the home address.
PhysicalAddressEntry paEntry1 = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
paEntry1.Street = "straße";
paEntry1.City = "stadt";
paEntry1.State = "D";
paEntry1.PostalCode = "88890";
paEntry1.CountryOrRegion = "Deutschland";
contact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = paEntry1;
contact.Save();
```

Comment: this is not working cause exchange user data can't be used.
<br>


 exchangeUserData exchangeUserData = new ExchangeUserData();
            exchangeUserData.Username = "c-sharp";
            exchangeUserData.Password = "c-sharp"; // c-sharp's Password
            ExchangeService service = service.ConnectToServiceWithImpersonation(exchangeUserData, impersonatedUserPrincipal);

Comment: Please be more specific than "this is not working". What happens when you try Andreas' suggestion? Do you get an error message? If so: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If your `c-sharp` user has the proper rights in Exchange, you should be able to do:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("c-sharp", "c-sharp", "domain");
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "test");
```

If this doesn't work for you, please comment below or update your question (there's an "edit" link under it) with the exact behavior you are seeing including any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sloved.

I found the bug... both of you are right just change:

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "test");
```

Into:

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test@domain.de");
```

Thats all ...

Great thanks to you